# Configure Widgets in a Sub-Dialog in a pyqt Main Window

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I have a GUI App with a Main Dialog and I added a button to it.
Pushing the button adds another "dialog" where the user has to input some values.
Both Ui-files are written with the QTDesigner and "dialog" has a "QtableWidget" with the object name "tableCo" I am not sure why I cannot change the properties of this tableWidget:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt  
from Main_Window import Ui_Dialog as Dlg
from dialog import Ui_MyDialog

class MainDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) 
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.buttonOK, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onOK) 
        self.connect(self.buttonAbbrechen, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onClose)

        self.connect(self.Button, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.on_Button_clicked)

    def on_Button_clicked(self, checked=None):
        if checked==None: return
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()


        some_list=["A","B","C"] 
        #a list in another python class from another script that changes so
        #the table properties have to be changed dynamically
        #here I just take a simple list as an example

        #the following two lines do not work (they work if tableCo is an 
        #object in the Main Dialog

        self.tableCo.setColumnCount(len(some_list))           
        self.tableCo.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(some_list)

    def onOK:
    ...
    def onClose:
    ...
```

If I push the button i see my "tableCo" widget, but the properties of the header have not changed, and after closing this sub-dialog I get the following error-message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/gui.py", line 88, in on_Button_clicked
    self.tableCo.setColumnCount(len(some_list))
AttributeError: 'MainDialog' object has no attribute 'tableCo'
```

What do i have to change in my code to configure a Widget in a sub-Dialog?

Comment: could you paste your code contains `tableCo` here or on codepad.org or somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code in your `on_Button_clicked`.

Firstly, you are attempting to call methods *after* the dialog has closed. When `exec_` is called, the dialog enters a blocking loop until the user closes the dialog. When the dialog closes, the following lines *will* get executed, but the dialog will be immediately garbage-collected after that when the function returns.

Secondly, you are attempting to access methods of the dialog using `self`, rather than via the local name `dialog`, which is why you are getting the `AttributeError`.

You can fix these problems by creating a subclass for the second dialog in the same way that you have for your `MainDialog` class:

```
class SubDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_MyDialog): 
    def __init__(self, some_list, parent=None): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.tableCo.setColumnCount(len(some_list))           
        self.tableCo.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(some_list)

class MainDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg):  
    ...    

    def on_Button_clicked(self, checked=None):
        if checked is None: return
        dialog = SubQDialog(some_list)
        dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: @user2956831. After the user has made changes and `dialog.exec_()` returns, you can still access its methods, attributes, etc. So you could use e.g. `dialog.tableCo.item(0, 0).text()` to get a text value, and then pass it to the main dialog via `self`.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure `tableCo` has that exact name and it's parented directly to the MainWindow? Seems like the properties are not being updated simply because there is no `self.tableCo`.